# NHibernate Mapping a Table Were the Primary Key is Also a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, hibernate

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
create table Users
(
 UserId int primary key identity not null
)

create table UserExternalKeys
(
 UserIdRef int primary key not null,
 ExternalKey varchar(50) unique not null
)

alter table UserExternalKeys
add constraint fk_UsersExternalKeys_Users
foreign key (UserIdRef)
references Users (UserId)
```

Each user can have a 0 or 1 external keys.  Things are setup this way because adding a nullable unique column to SQL Server does not allow for more than 1 null value.

Based on [Ayende's post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx), it seems like this could be handled using a `<one-to-one>` mapping.  However, this would require the `UserExternalKeys` table to have its own primary key.

The new schema would look something like this:

```
create table Users
(
    UserId int primary key identity not null,
    ExternalKeyRef int null
)

create table UserExternalKeys
(
    UserExternalKeyId int primary key identity not null,
    ExternalKey varchar(50) unique not null
)

alter table Users
add constraint fk_Users_UsersExternalKeys
foreign key (ExternalKeyRef)
references UserExternalKeys (UserExternalKeyId)
```

I think this would work, but it feels like I would only be adding the `UserExternalKeyId` column to appease NHibernate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Adding columns just to appease NHibernate is like a rite of passage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user can have 0 or 1 external keys why not design the tables as:

```
create table Users
(
    UserId int primary key identity not null
    ExternalKey varchar(50) null
)
```

and use one of the known workarounds for this problem. If you're using SQL Server 2008 you can use a [filtered index](http://www.proace.com/2010/02/11/unique-constraints-on-nullable-columns-in-sql-server-2008/). If you're using an earlier version you can use a trigger, an indexed view (2005), or the [nullbuster workaround](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32267298/unique-constraint-with-multiple-nulls.aspx).

You could also keep your original schema and map the relationship as one-to-many from Users to UserExternalKeys. Map the collection as a private member and expose access to it through a property:

```
private IList<UserExternalKeys> _externalKeys;

public string ExternalKeys
{
    get
    {
        if (_externalKeys.Count() == 1) 
        {
            return _externalKeys.ElementAt(0).ExternalKey;
        }
        else
        {
            // return null or empty string if count = 0, throw exception if > 1
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if (_externalKeys.Count() == 0) { // add key and set value }
        else { // set value if count = 1, throw exception if > 1 } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had this issue in the past but had never heard of the nullbuster workaround nor had I thought of the indexed view.  (I've used a trigger to do this which kinda stinks).  The filtered index would be the best, but I am stuck on 2005 for the time being.

I ended up using the 2nd schema and creating a many-to-one relationship from Users to Keys due to some legacy code I did not want to fuss with.  But truth be told, I like some of your suggestions better :)